# pl/sql conversion from number to string

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i need to convert number to string in pl/sql without using the inbuilt functions , we should use string/module operations for this. for example  if the input is 123 then the output should be one hundred and twenty three can anyone give me suggestions about this pls?

Comment: why can't you use the built in functions?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this in SQL or PL/SQL using the following:

In SQL:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(<number_column>,'j'), 'jsp') 
  FROM <table>;
```

In PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  v_number NUMBER := 56;
  v_text   VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  v_text := to_char(to_date(v_number,'j'), 'jsp');
END;
```

More information from AskTom here:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123#PAGETOP

I suppose it really depends upon what level of "in-built" functions you are going to artificially prevent yourself using and why?

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 didn't know about the JSP trick. Anyone know where that is documented?

Comment: Don't know where it is documented, I found the asktom question a while ago when I had a similar issue.

Comment: +2 for the link and one more for the answer!

Comment: Found the documentation on it: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABGDDFB